# Why does my download queue break when called faster after each other?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webclient

I am using the following script to download XML files from a external site, but when the function is called fast after each other (Fast switching of tables to show) the queue seems to slip up.

When the function is called in a normal manner it works just fine, but when the user starts to switch between tables at a faster pace, the data won't load. It does not give any exceptions besides on some rare occasions it will say that the queue is busy. All tough I can't seem to find what is causing this queue to slip.

```
public void PreObtainData(ref MonavisaRequestForm request, string dateAndTime, string fileDateAndTime)
{
    if (!initialized)
        initialize();
    try
    {
        if (!request.webclient.IsBusy && requestQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            request.url = request.url.Replace("&", "%26");
            request.url = request.url.Replace("+", "%2B");
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost/login.php?username={0}&password={1}&request={2}", request.username, request.password, request.url));
            request.webclient.DownloadFile(uri, @"Nioo Graph Data " + fileDateAndTime + ".xml"); 
        }
        else if (!request.webclient.IsBusy && requestQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost/login.php?username={0}&password={1}&request={2}", requestQueue.Peek().username, requestQueue.Peek().password, requestQueue.Peek().url));
            requestQueue.Peek().webclient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
            requestQueue.Dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
            requestQueue.Enqueue(request);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
    {
        //if (ex.Status != System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queues are not designed to be accessed from multiple threads, and any number of things can go wrong when you do so.  You should use a `ConcurrentQueue` or a `BlockingCollection` (which uses a `ConcurrentQueue`), as it is specifically designed to be used from multiple threads.

Comment: Unity does not seem to support concurrentqueue nor blockingcollection thou,

Comment: @MXD Then you'll need to use some other tool to synchronize access to the queue or avoid the shared resource.